# My Authentication is not working in published mode

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

If i disable Javascript SDK my page are blank. If i active my page is equal to image.png. My app are in production mode and his permissions public_access and email in advanced mode.

I already try everything[image]